# TypeBuilder - Adding attributes

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, custom-attributes, typebuilder

I have a helper class that uses a TypeBuilder to construct a dynamic type. It is used as follows :

```
var tbh = new TypeBuilderHelper("MyType");
tbh.AddProperty<float>("Number", 0.0f);
tbh.AddProperty<string>("String", "defaultStringValue");
tbh.Close();

var i1 = tbh.CreateInstance();
var i2 = tbh.CreateInstance();
```

I now want to add support for property attributes (existing attribute types, not dynamically generated types), along the lines of :

```
public class TypeBuilderHelper
    {
        public void AddProperty<T>(string name, T defaultValue, params Attribute[] attributes)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

public class SomeAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SomeAttribute(float a) { }
        public SomeAttribute(float a, int b) { }
        public SomeAttribute(float a, double b, string c) { }
    }

 var tbh2 = new TypeBuilderHelper("MyType2");
 tbh2.AddProperty<float>("Number", 0.0f, new SomeAttribute(0.0f, 1));
 tbh2.AddProperty<string>("String", "defaultStringValue");
 tbh2.Close();

 var i3 = tbh.CreateInstance();
 var i4 = tbh.CreateInstance();
```

But I'm not sure how that would work. I'm creating the properties using the PropertyBuilder, but the CustomAttributeBuilder wants a constructor signature and the constructor args, where as all I'll have is an instance of a constructed Attribute.

Comment: Somewhat unclear. Do you want to create Attributes at runtime or just add existing Attributes to properties created at runtime?

Comment: existing attribute types, not dynamically generated types :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An instance of an attribute isn't helpful here you need to define the constructor and the values that should be called. A simple solution might be to change the AddProperty Signature and exchange the params Attribute Parameter with a params CustomAttributeBuilder Parameter and construct Builder instances instead of attributes.

```
var ci = typeof(SomeAttribute).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(float), typeof(int) });
var builder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ci, new object[] { 0.0f, 1 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but the helper is supposed to make things easier/user friendly. I don't think your suggestion really helps much

Comment: Then you need to come up with a clever encapsulation but the instance won't help. You need at least the Attribute Type and the values you want to    put into the constructor. You can't extract how an instance was created from the instance.

Comment: Sure, I don't think there is a clean type safe solution to this. I was just kind of hoping there was something I had missed that could take the instance itself.