# Attach existing CustomAttribute to field using C#

Tags: c#, reflection, custom-attributes

I noticed that this is a duplicate of [TypeBuilder - Adding attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264032/typebuilder-adding-attributes) so requesting to close.

I have some code that adds a field dynamically to a TypeBuilder.
the field has an existing annotation/customattribute as well which I want to add.
How can I do this?

```
    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder tb, string propertyName, Type propertyType, ColumnAttribute annotation)
    {
        FieldBuilder fieldBuilder = tb.DefineField("_" + propertyName, propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);

        PropertyBuilder propertyBuilder = tb.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);
        MethodBuilder getPropMthdBldr = tb.DefineMethod("get_" + propertyName, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getIl = getPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();

        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setPropMthdBldr =
            tb.DefineMethod("set_" + propertyName,
                MethodAttributes.Public |
                MethodAttributes.SpecialName |
                MethodAttributes.HideBySig,
                null, new[] { propertyType });

        ILGenerator setIl = setPropMthdBldr.GetILGenerator();
        Label modifyProperty = setIl.DefineLabel();
        Label exitSet = setIl.DefineLabel();

        setIl.MarkLabel(modifyProperty);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);

        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        setIl.MarkLabel(exitSet);
        setIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getPropMthdBldr);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setPropMthdBldr);

        ????????
        Code the add the annotation to the property here.
    }
```

Comment: Use a `CustomAttributeBuilder`.

Comment: @thehennyy That is what I have been trying to do. Can you post an example?

Comment: If you have tried that, please provide the code that did not work. The msdn contains full examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.customattributebuilder?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Is `ColumnAttribute` in the argument list a typo?

Comment: @Ackdari it's a class name. The customattribute that should be added to the property.

Comment: @thehennyy the msdn example is only if you want to create a new attribute, I have an existing one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeBuilder - Adding attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264032/typebuilder-adding-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a `CustomAttributeBuilder` for your attribute:

```
Type[] ctorParams = new Type[] { /*Types of your Attributes Constructor*/ };
ConstructorInfo classCtorInfo = typeof(ColumnAttribute).GetConstructor(ctorParams);

CustomAttributeBuilder myCABuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(
                        classCtorInfo,
                        /*arguments for your Attribute*/);

propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(myCABuilder);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have an existing customattribute though. I changed the question to make that more clear.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. The CustomAttribute has to be created dynamically.
See this question for more info. [TypeBuilder - Adding attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264032/typebuilder-adding-attributes)